# some troubles with CreateView in the Django

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views, django-class-based-views

```
class Biochemical_analysis_of_blood(CreateView):
    model = BiochemicalAnalysisOfBlood
    form_class = BiochemicalAnalysisOfBloodForm
    template_name = "biochemical_analysis_of_blood.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("patients")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Biochemical_analysis_of_blood, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        patient = Patient.objects.get(id=1)
        context["patient"] = patient
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        analysis = Analyzes()
        sid = transaction.savepoint()
        analysis.name = request.POST["name"]
        analysis.patient_id = Patient.objects.get(id=1)
        analysis.who_send = request.POST["who_send"]
        analysis.who_is_doctor = request.POST["who_is_doctor"]
        analysis.lab_user_id = Doctor.objects.get(id=request.POST["lab_user_id"])
        analysis.additional_lab_user = request.POST["lab_user_add"]
        analysis.date = '2017-06-18'
        analysis.type = 3
        analysis.date_analysis = '2017-06-18'
        analysis.save()
        return super(Biochemical_analysis_of_blood, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I have next algorithm:

1. Render `BiochemicalAnalysisOfBloodForm`  to the user
2. When he fills fields and presses button "save" I create a new instance of `Analyzes()` and fill it programmatically and when in the post method I call `super().post()` then users data will be written to the model `BiochemicalAnalysisOfBlood` automatically? But I have next error:

> NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   laboratory_biochemicalanalysisofblood.analysis_id

How can I in hand mode add to the model to the field "analysis" the early created instance of `Analyzes()`? I don't understand this class to the end where I can find information about all it's opportunities

Comment: Could you post the content of your form BiochemicalAnalysisOfBloodForm ?

Comment: Why not have a separate autofilled id and have analysisid be a nullable field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of your algorithm should reside in your form, because you want to pass the analysis_id to the instance being saved

```
class BiochemicalAnalysisOfBloodForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        analysis = Analyzes()
        sid = transaction.savepoint()
        analysis.name = self.data["name"]
        analysis.patient_id = Patient.objects.get(id=1)
        analysis.who_send = self.data["who_send"]
        analysis.who_is_doctor = self.data["who_is_doctor"]
        analysis.lab_user_id = Doctor.objects.get(id=self.data["lab_user_id"])
        analysis.additional_lab_user = self.data["lab_user_add"]
        analysis.date = '2017-06-18'
        analysis.type = 3
        analysis.date_analysis = '2017-06-18'
        analysis.save()
        # Your analysis is created, attach it to the form instance object
        self.instance.analysis_id = analysis.id
        return super().save(commit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the super().post you can modify the request.POST data to include your analysis id:

```
request.POST['analysis_id'] = analysis.id
```

that might help.

Also note that if the form validation fails in super().post, you will still have created an Analysis object which might not be useful. You could use override the form_invalid method of the CreateView to handle this.

Comment: I did it and have next error "This QueryDict instance is immutable" and then I add next code     
" if not request.POST._mutable:
            request.POST._mutable = True" and again this error "NOT NULL constraint failed: laboratory_biochemicalanalysisofblood.analysis_id"
@Lucas Moeskops

Comment: Ah, yes it's a bit more complicated. request.POST should ideally not be edited, and you can modify what parameters are sent to the form by overriding `get_form_kwargs` method on the CreateView. Then you will need to create a custom dictionary which contains request.POST and analysis_id. Then if the analysis exists, it should work.